# How to loop through the items in the list which is returned by hostnames from the inventory groups

Tags: ansible

Loop through the items. And items are from Inventory groups.

I tried almost all the solutions posted in stackoverflow, but no luck.
Here is my playbook:

```yaml
 ---
 - hosts: dev   
   gather_facts: yes
   become: true   
   become_method: su   
   become_user: xxxxx
 
   tasks:
   - name: Update the file contents
     replace:
       path: "/path/to/file{{ item.path  }}.xml"
       regexp: '(xxxxxxx[\s\S]*yyyyyyy$)'
       replace: "/zzz/zzzz/{{ item.replace }}.dat /qqqq/qqqqq/q"
       backup: yes
     with_items:
       - { path: "{{ groups['dev'] }}", replace: "{{ groups['pc'] }}" }
```

And this is my inventory:

```ini
[dev] 
host1 
host2
 
[pc] 
1234 
6789
```

I want to execute the task : "Update the file contents" for every hostname under dev group for item.path and item.pc

The result of my execution is:

```
failed: [host1] (item={u'path': [u'host1', u'host2'], u'replace': [u'1234', u'6789']}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "
item": {"path": ["host1", "host2"], "replace": ["1234", "6789"]}, "msg": "Path /path/to/file[u'host1', u'host2'].xml does not exist !", "rc": 257}

failed: [host2] (item={u'path': [u'host1', u'host2'], u'replace': [u'1234', u'6789']}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "
item": {"path": ["host1", "host2"], "replace": ["1234", "6789"]}, "msg": "Path /path/to/file[u'host1', u'host2'].xml does not exist !", rc": 257}
```

Expected output:

```
[host1] (item={u'path': [u'host1'], u'replace': [u'1234']}) "msg": "Path /path/to/file/host1.xml 
[host2] (item={u'path': [u'host2'], u'replace': [u'6789']}) "msg": "Path /path/to/file/host2.xml
```

This works fine if I have only 1 hostname in the dev group. I need the task to work for all the hosts when the number of hosts are more than 1.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format the code correctly. There's help for that in the editor.

Comment: My bad it was not formatted properly as this was my 1st post. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. How do you intend to map the path you pick in group dev to the replace term you pick in group pc (since number of hosts can be different)?

Comment: My apologies if the question is not clear! Number of hosts in dev and entries in pc will always have the same number of entries.

Answer (score 0):

According to your desired output, there is no need to loop over all hosts.
There is even no need to run the task on the `pc` hosts group.

```yaml
- name: Update the file contents
  replace:
    path: "/path/to/file/{{ inventory_hostname_short }}.xml"
    regexp: '(xxxxxxx[\s\S]*yyyyyyy$)'
    replace: "/zzz/zzzz/{{ groups['pc'][groups['dev'].index(inventory_hostname)].split('.')[0] }}.dat /qqqq/qqqqq/q"
    backup: yes
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['dev']
```

I avoided having the domain name in the hostnames.

```yaml
{{ groups['pc'][groups['dev'].index(inventory_hostname)].split('.')[0] }}
```

Here I'm getting the host from group `[pc]`, which its index number is equivalent to the host from group `[dev]` which the task is currently running on.

- when running on `host1` which has index number `0` in group `[dev]`  ==> `groups['pc'][0]`
- when running on `host2` which has index number `1` in group `[dev]`  ==> `groups['pc'][1]`

With `.split('.')[0]` I'm getting the hostname without domain name.